# javafx: How can I format a double property for binding?

Tags: java, javafx

I have two double properties `price1` and `price2`. I know that I can bind it to a label like this:

```
    Locale locale  = new Locale("en", "UK");
    fxLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("price1/price2: %.3f/%.3f",.price1Property(),price2Property()));
```

but the displayed number does not have any commas separators (i.e. 123456.789 is shown instead of 123,456.789). Ideally, I would like to be do something like the following:

```
    String pattern = "###,###.###;-###,###.###";
    DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
    df.applyPattern(pattern);
    df.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(10);
    // bind df.format(value from price1 and price 2 property) to the label
```

But I have no idea how to do this on a property. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the JavaFX high level binding API, you can change the format string and pass the locale to `Binding.format`:

```
Locale locale  = new Locale("en", "UK");
fxLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format(locale, "price1/price2: %,.3f/%,.3f", price1Property(), price2Property()));
```

In this example, the ',' flag is used in the format string (all options and possibilities documented in the [java.util.Formatter API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

You can also use the low level binding API:

```
StringBinding stringBinding = new StringBinding() {

    private final static Locale LOCALE  = new Locale("en", "UK");
    private final static DecimalFormat DF;

    static {
        String pattern = "###,###.###;-###,###.###";
        DF = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(LOCALE);
        DF.applyPattern(pattern);
        DF.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
        DF.setMaximumFractionDigits(10);
    }

    public StringBinding() {
        super.bind(price1Property(), price2Property());
    }

    @Override
    protected String computeValue() {
        return "price1/price2 " + DF.format(price1Property().get()) + "/" + DF.format(price2Property().get());
    }
};
fxLabel.bind(stringBinding);
```